# Mapbox + SwiftUI: UI Refresh not propagating

Tags: swiftui, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have integrated Mapbox with SwiftUI using the following example:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-swiftui-demo

It works fine. However when trying to display other @State variables on the View Stack, the UI Refresh propagation stops going down to the Mapbox call `updateUIView()`

For example, you can replicate the problem by replacing ContentView.swift from the above repository with the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var annotations: [MGLPointAnnotation] = [
        MGLPointAnnotation(title: "Mapbox", coordinate: .init(latitude: 37.791434, longitude: -122.396267))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                MapView(annotations: $annotations).centerCoordinate(.init(latitude: 37.791293, longitude: -122.396324)).zoomLevel(16)
                Button(action: {
                    let rand = Float.random(in: 37.79...37.80)
                    self.annotations.append(MGLPointAnnotation(title: "Mapbox", coordinate: .init(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(rand), longitude: -122.396261)))
                }) {
                    Text("Button")
                    Text("\(self.annotations.count)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Running the above code indicates that the `Text("\(self.annotations.count)")` UI gets updated - however, the annotations are not refreshed (hence `updateUIView()` is not called).

If I comment `// Text("\(self.annotations.count)")` then annotations are refreshed (and `updateUIView()` is called)

Does anybody have any ideas of what might be the issue? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you report but to mapbox owner?

Comment: I have reported https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-swiftui-demo/issues/3#issuecomment-600902173

But the owner suggested posting questions on SO also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here thanks to this post

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-swiftui-demo/issues/3#issuecomment-623905509

In order for this to work it is necessary to update the UIView being rendered inside Mapview:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: Context) {
    updateAnnotations(uiView)
    trackUser()
}

private func updateAnnotations(_ view: MGLMapView) {
    if let currentAnnotations = view.annotations {
        view.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
    }
    view.addAnnotations(annotations)
}
```